# setting property of nsobject subclass by means of selector setProperty

Tags: swift, nsobject

I have subclass of `NSObject` and I can set value of my subclass with:

```
performSelector(onMainThread:  Selector("setNameOfProperty:"), with: "myName", waitUntilDone: true)
```

Actually, I did not write any method named `setMethodProperty` of course.

So here is my simple class:

```
class Post: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var statusText: String?
    var profileImageName: String?
    var statusImageName: String?
    var numLikes: NSNumber?
    var numComments: NSNumber?

    var location: Location?

    override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        if key == "location" {
            location = Location()
            location?.setValuesForKeys(value as! [String: AnyObject])
        } else {
            super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

A then from another class I just invoke method `performSelector`:

```
let samplePost = Post()
samplePost.performSelector(onMainThread:  Selector("setStatusText:"), with: "myName", waitUntilDone: true)
```

I am looking for any information about that interesting thing, but I couldn't. Maybe someone has the link about it or just know what is this behavior. If you can write about it to clarify situation.

Comment: So uhhh, what's your question?

Comment: "Key-value coding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about key-value coding in [About Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html), specifically:

> Objects typically adopt key-value coding when they inherit from NSObject (directly or indirectly), which both adopts the NSKeyValueCoding protocol and provides a default implementation for the essential methods. Such an object enables other objects, through a compact messaging interface, to do the following:
>
> **Access object properties.**
>
> The protocol specifies methods, such as the generic getter `valueForKey:` and the generic setter `setValue:forKey:`, for accessing object properties by their name, or key, parameterized as a string. The default implementation of these and related methods use the key to locate and interact with the underlying data, as described in Accessing Object Properties.

By subclassing `NSObject`, `Post` class implements `NSKeyValueCoding`.

Basically it means that the properties defined in `Post` generate corresponding getter and setter methods, which means that they can be accessed using `performSelector`. This Key-Value coding allows you to perform selectors for getting or setting even properties which names you don't know during compilation - selector can be created from a string variable.

In case you will decide to migrate the project to Swift 4, note that you will have to either mark each property that you want to access this way using `@objc`, or use `@objcMembers` annotation on the whole class.